# C++ Function not working as expected

Tags: c++, debugging

So I know this is a very broad topic, but I'm not sure how to describe it and I'm not sure where the bug is. So I'm making a game in the console window, a roguelike-rpg, (I haven't done the random dungeon yet, but I've done it in other languages.) and I'm having problems dealing with walls.

I have a function called `placeMeeting(REAL X, REAL Y)` that I use to check for collisions, but it appears to be returning bad values and I couldn't tell you why. I have couple of macros defined: `#define AND &&` and `#define REAL double`.

Here is the function:

```
bool GlobalClass::placeMeeting(REAL X, REAL Y)
{
    //The return value -- False until proven otherwise
    bool collision = false;

    //Loop through all walls to check for a collision
    for(int i = 0; i < wallCount; i++)
    {
        //If there was a collision, 'say' so
        if (X == wallX[ i ] AND Y == wallY[ i ])
        {
            //Set 'collision' to true
            collision = true;
        }
    }

    return collision;
}
```

But the strange catch is that it only doesn't work when displaying the screen. The player collides with them all the same even though there not displayed. Even stranger, only the first wall is being displayed.
Here is where the walls are defined:

```
int wallCount;

//Array of walls
REAL wallX[ 1 ];
REAL wallY[ 1 ];
```

and

```
wallCount  = 1;
//Basic wall stuff; basically just a placeholder
wallX[ 0 ] = 10;
wallY[ 0 ] = 10;
```

So I have a function used to render the screen (In the console window of course.) and it looks like this:

```
for (int y = oGlobal.viewY; y < oGlobal.viewY + oGlobal.viewHeight; y++)
{
    //The inner 'x' loop of the view
    for(int x = oGlobal.viewX; x < oGlobal.viewX + oGlobal.viewWidth; x++)
    {
        //Call the function to check this spot and print what it returns
        screen += oGlobal.checkSpot(x, y);
    }
}
```

That's not the whole function, just the actual screen refreshing. After 'screen' is printed to the screen, to reduce buffer time. And of course, checkSpot:

```
STRING GlobalClass::checkSpot(REAL x, REAL y)
{
    STRING spriteAtSpot;

    //First check for the player
    if (x == oPlayer.x AND y == oPlayer.y)
    {
        spriteAtSpot = oPlayer.sprite;
    }
    else if (placeMeeting(x, y)) //ITS TEH WALL SUCKAS
    {
        spriteAtSpot = WALL_SPRITE;
    }
    else //Nothing here, return a space
    {
        spriteAtSpot = EMPTY_SPRITE;
    }

    //Return the sprite
    return spriteAtSpot;
}
```

I know it's a lot of code, but I really don't know where I screwed up.

I really appreciate any help!

P.S. Here is an image to help understand
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu9ZD.png

Comment: Why did you go and define `AND`? It's C++. Embrace it. The more you fight it by making behave as something else more familiar, the more confused you'll be. Using `#define` in C++ code for this sort of thing is severely frowned upon. If you must, use a `typedef` for aliases, but obscuring the type of an argument or variable is counter-productive.

Comment: Erm why do you have AND and REAL defined as macros? What is wrong with typedef and using the language's own syntax?

Comment: Also, `STRING` vs `std::string`

Comment: Putting aside that you defined AND and REAL... try `#define REAL int` for a moment and see if that changes things.

Comment: Note that C already defines a seldom-used `and` keyword equivalent to `&&`, so there's really no excuse for `#define AND`

Comment: @eric Apparently [C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and), and C ([C95](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_alternative)) have support for this. Didn't know that.

Comment: @tadman: That was what I meant to type. Thanks for the reference though.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). [What every computer programmer should know about floating point](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html).

Comment: What @MooingDuck said was why I suggested trying int for REAL. I didn't really see anything out of sorts in the above code using doubles, but given that there may be a lot more we aren't seeing, it's a candidate.

Comment: For the #define stuff, I made REAL so if I wanted to change the data type later I could just change what REAL is equal to instead of going through all the code and renaming it, but I'll change it to typedef because apparently that is better.

Comment: But for AND, in C++ there is no keyword and...

Comment: @Paulo: How can you dispute the existence of the `and` keyword after a link to the reference!?

Comment: I typed in 'and' on Visual Studio and it gives me an error, perhaps it was strictly C, but it's not usable in my IDE...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but since rogue-like games are tile-based, is it necessary to make the X and Y values doubles? I remember being told that doubles are finicky to compare, since even if you assume they should be equal, they could be very slightly off, causing comparison to return false when you'd think it would return true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure we have enough of your code to debug it, but I have developed a Rogue-like console game, and here is my $.02...

1. **Start over**. You seem to be doing this in a very non-OO way (GlobalClass?). Consider objects such as Level (aggregates entire level), DungeonObject (essentially each space on the level; it's a base class that can be inherited from into Wall, Player, etc.). Doing this will make the programming much easier.
2. **Embrace the suck**. C++ syntax may suck, but the more you fight against it, the harder it will be to learn. Use && and the built-in datatypes. It won't take long to get used to.
3. **Rouge-like locations** are essentially **integer-based**. Use integer for x, y locations, not doubles (the biggest built-in data-type). Not only is it more efficient, you'll find debugging much easier.
4. **Start in the small**. Start with a 5 x 5 dungeon level to get the basics down. Then, if you've designed it correctly, scaling up to a 10x10 or 25x25 will be much easier.

That's how I developed my game; I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I don't dislike C++ syntax, I like it a lot more than any other language. But this post was about the wall problem, not the roguelike dungeon thing, I've done that before in a different langauge... But I will definitely change the doubles to ints.

Comment: But what do you mean by non-OO, I'm using objects wherever I can... The globalclass holds 'global' variables (Because actual globals are bad) and the player uses a base class, perhaps I should make the wall its own class.

Comment: Like I said, I couldn't see your entire design from the code you posted, but the only class I saw used was "GlobalClass". I assumed that it was the only class you used.

Comment: I apologize, I thought if I included more code people wouldn't want to read through it all... I come from the Gamemaker Community where if you have more than 10 lines of code in a question people just quit.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the use of double instead of int, I see something strange in your definition of walls:

```
int wallCount;

//Array of walls
REAL wallX[ 1 ];
REAL wallY[ 1 ];
```

and

```
wallCount  = 1;
//Basic wall stuff; basically just a placeholder
wallX[ 0 ] = 10;
wallY[ 0 ] = 10;
```

You are defining a variable called `wallCount`, which you later use to go through the elements of your array in your `placeMeeting` function:

```
//Loop through all walls to check for a collision
for(int i = 0; i < wallCount; i++)
```

Then why don't you use `wallCount` to define the size of your arrays? Of course you can't use that syntax, because the size of a static array must be known at compile time, so you should either use `new` or `std::vector`, but still you shouldn't have a variable that defines the length of the array and then use *another* value when you actually create the array, it is a source of bugs if you fail to keep them aligned. So for example you could do this:

```
const int wallCount = 1;
int* wallX = new int[wallCount];
int* wallY = new int[wallCount];
```

But there's a bigger problem: why are you creating arrays of size 1? You are having only one wall! It doesn't really make sense to have arrays of size 1, unless you intend to use another value but you have reduced it to 1 for debugging purposes. But, you wrote this:

> Even stranger, only the first wall is being displayed.

That's because you only have 1 wall!

By the way, the way you have designed your data isn't the one I would use. From your `checkSpot` I understand this: `oPlayer.x` and `oPlayer.y` are the coordinates of your player, and `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the tile you have to draw (and for which you need to choose the appropriate sprite). If in your map you have 3 walls, you have to put 3 values in `wallX` and 3 in `wallY`, and you must make sure that you keep the 2 arrays "aligned" (if the coordinates of your second wall are for example x=10 and y=20, you could get confused, or have buggy code, and instead of saving it as

```
wallX[1] = 10;
wallY[1] = 20;
```

you might write

```
wallX[1] = 10;
wallY[2] = 20; // wrong index!
```

so it's one more source of bugs), and worse, you must check that they are consistent with other arrays of other objects: you could have, for example, doors, and then following your approach you'd have `doorX[]` and `doorY[]`, and how can you be sure that you don't have a wall and a door at the same place? Like, if you had

```
doorX[0] = 10;
doorY[0] = 20;
```

it would be at the same place as the wall, and the error isn't obvious, because you'd have to cross-check all your arrays to find it. So I would suggest to have a `level[height][width]` instead, and to have a wall at x=10 and y=20 you could use `level[10][20] = 'w';`. This would ensure that you only have ONE object per tile. Besides, checking for collisions would be faster: with your approach, if you have 50 walls you need 50 checks; with mine, you always only need one. Ok, performance is certainly not an issue in these games, but still I think you should consider my approach (unless there are other reasons to prefer yours, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to try this stuff. But as for the wall array thing, there is a function that creates a wall and increments the wall count, but could that be causing problems?

Comment: @Paulo: How are you increasing the size of the array when you increase wallCount?

Comment: `void GlobalClass::addWall(REAL X, REAL Y)
{
 //Create a new wall
 wallX[ wallCount ] = X;
 wallY[ wallCount ] = Y;

 //Increment the wall count
 wallCount++;
}` Is the exact function I use